# Twitter bot issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, reddit

I have made a Twitter bot that every time Lil Uzi Vert or Playboi Carti tweets it should post on their subreddit. The issue I have is that it keeps spamming Lil Uzi Vert's last tweet on both subreddits. And because of this I also got banned.

If I try to follow only my twitter account it works.

Found the problem: whenever someone likes or retweets their tweet, it will count as another new status and therefore post it on Reddit. (It does not matter which post it is, could be even older). How can I make this to work only when one of them tweets or replies?

```
import praw
import tweepy


def submit(status):
    r = praw.Reddit(
        client_id="",
        client_secret="",
        username="",
        password="",
        user_agent=""
    )
    subreddit = r.subreddit('playboicarti')
    subreddit.submit("new tweet", status)
    subreddit = r.subreddit('liluzivert')
    subreddit.submit("new tweet", status)


# Twitter part
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api

    def on_status(self, status):
        status = f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{status.id}\nHe said: {status.text}"
        submit(status)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print("Error detected" + str(status))


def twitter():
    # Authenticate to Twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
    auth.set_access_token("",
                          "")

    # Create API object
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                     wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    tweets_listener = MyStreamListener(api)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
    stream.filter(follow=["101263750", "1599608046"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitter()
```

Comment: When you call  status in class MyStreamListener you go to one subreddit and post with a fixed status. Then, with the same fixed status you change to another subreddit and do a new post. When do you change the status for the other subreddit?

Comment: @SergioR I don't, because I want to post the same thing on both subreddits. The fans like both artists

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy, as far as I know, does not support filtering out retweets.

You can use [python-twitter](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'s [GetUserTimeline()](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html#twitter.api.Api.GetUserTimeline) which has a boolean keyword argument `include_rts`.

Now the only issue is that python-twitter doesn't have a stream listener setup so you have to replicate it using a loop and `time.sleep()` so you don't go over the rate limit; like this:

```
import twitter 
import time

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                  consumer_secret='', 
                  access_token_key='', 
                  access_token_secret='') 

user_id = 101263750

while True: 
    try: 
        statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(user_id=user_id,include_rts=False,
                                       since_id=max_id,trim_user=True) 
        for status in statuses: 
            print(status.text) 
            max_id = status.id 
    except NameError:
        max_id = api.GetUserTimeline(user_id=user_id,include_rts=False,count=1,
                                     trim_user=True)[0].id 
    time.sleep(30)
```

I leave to you making this fit into what you're doing with reddit.

Comment: Hey, first I would like to thank you, I tried what you said, I tested everything, but when I send a status it won't do anything. I did change the uid with mine. The issue is I think at for status in statuses loop. It simply won't find any statuses I guess. Even though I did send a tweet.